# Height of a div doesn't change CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a animated navigation bar. Now I want to make the height of the div 0px, so that if I click on a button, the menu will pop-out. But the height stays the same if I change it to 0px:

I hope someone could help me.

HTML:

```
<div id="mobileMenu">
    <a href="#"> <h1> Home </h1> </a>
    <a href="#"> <h1> Blog </h1> </a>
    <a href="#"> <h1> Lorem ipsum </h1> </a>
    <a href="#"> <h1> Lorem ipsum </h1> </a>
    <a href="#"> <h1> Contact </h1> </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#mobileMenu {
    position: fixed;
    height: 0px;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}

#mobileMenu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

#mobileMenu h1 {
    padding: 20px 0px;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    font-family: OpenSans-Regular;
    padding-left: 15%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `overflow: hidden;`. The height is `0` but the content is overflowing, and `overflow` is `visible` by default.

```css
div {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="mobileMenu">
  <a href="#">
    <h1> Home </h1> </a>
  <a href="#">
    <h1> Blog </h1> </a>
  <a href="#">
    <h1> Lorem ipsum </h1> </a>
  <a href="#">
    <h1> Lorem ipsum </h1> </a>
  <a href="#">
    <h1> Contact </h1> </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a CSS rule: set in #mobileMenu `display:none` and via JS change with `display:block` dynamically

```css
#mobileMenu {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  height: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

#mobileMenu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

#mobileMenu h1 {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  font-family: OpenSans-Regular;
  padding-left: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div id="mobileMenu">
  <a href="#">
    <h1> Home </h1>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <h1> Blog </h1>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <h1> Lorem ipsum </h1>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <h1> Lorem ipsum </h1>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <h1> Contact </h1>
  </a>
</div>
```